# my script doesn't run although i tried different cases

Tags: mysql, sql

Below you can see my script , when try to run CREATE PROCEDURE, it always gives syntax error , please let me know what is wrong?

I triead to delete ";" in front of END IF on create procedure  and also I tried to change position of END IF

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS parts (
    part_no VARCHAR(18) PRIMARY KEY,
    description VARCHAR(40),
    cost DECIMAL(10 , 2 ) NOT NULL,
    price DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE PROCEDURE `check_parts`(IN cost DECIMAL(10,2), IN price DECIMAL(10,2))
BEGIN
    IF cost < 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'check constraint on parts.cost failed';
    END IF;

    IF price < 0 THEN
 SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001'
 SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'check constraint on parts.price failed';
    END IF;

    IF price < cost THEN
 SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45002'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'check constraint on parts.price & parts.cost failed';
    END IF;

END
```

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Thanks for quick response but still gives syntax error

Comment: Apart from not setting delimiters there are no syntax errors. Please review https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to change the delimeters, because in the procedure written, it will stop at the 1st ";"

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `check_parts`(IN cost DECIMAL(10,2), IN price DECIMAL(10,2))
BEGIN
    IF cost < 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
          SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'check constraint on parts.cost failed';
    END IF;

    IF price < 0 THEN
      SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001'
         SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'check constraint on parts.price failed';
    END IF;

    IF price < cost THEN
       SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45002'
         SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'check constraint on parts.price & parts.cost failed';
    END IF;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Should work.

Comment: below you can see error Query execution failed

Reason:
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMETER' at line 1

Comment: not running , the error code is "Query execution failed

Reason:
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMETER' at line 1"

Comment: DELIM**I**TER not DELIMETER

Comment: Thank you sir , it was my mistake but the old problem still continue. thee error code is "SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6"